# Create a Bitmap from an Image

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

I have an Image object which is a jpg picture taken by the camera and I need to create a Bitmap from it.

Is there any way to do it besides using [BMPGenerator](http://code.google.com/p/openlapi/source/browse/trunk/tests/thinktank/j2me/BMPGenerator.java?r=372) class? I'm working on a commercial project and I don't think I can use it due to the GPLv3 license.

So far this is the code I have. Can I do something with it?

```
    FileConnection file = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file://" + imagePath, Connector.READ_WRITE);
    InputStream is = file.openInputStream();
    Image capturedImage = Image.createImage(is);
```

I tried this but I wasn't able to get the correct filepaht and the image is stuck in null

```
    EncodedImage image = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource(filePath);
    byte[] array = image.getData();
    capturedBitmap = image.getBitmap();
```

Comment: What kind of Image object is it? A PNG, a pixel array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!
Well, almost.
Used the following method but the image is rotated 90 degrees.
Going to fix that with [this](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Rotate-and-scale-bitmaps/ta-p/492524)

```
public Bitmap loadIconFromSDcard(String imgname){

    FileConnection fcon = null;
    Bitmap icon = null;

    try {

        fcon = (FileConnection)Connector.open(imgname, Connector.READ);
        if(fcon.exists()) {
            byte[] content = new byte[(int) fcon.fileSize()];
              int readOffset = 0;
              int readBytes = 0;
              int bytesToRead = content.length - readOffset;
              InputStream is = fcon.openInputStream();
              while (bytesToRead > 0) {
                readBytes = is.read(content, readOffset, bytesToRead);
                if (readBytes < 0) {
                  break;
                }
                readOffset += readBytes;
                bytesToRead -= readBytes;
              }
              is.close();
            EncodedImage image = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(content,0,content.length);
            icon = image.getBitmap();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }finally{
        // Close the connections
        try{ if(fcon != null) fcon.close(); }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }

    return icon;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `videoControl.getSnapshot(null)` and then `Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmapFromBytes(raw, 0, raw.length, 1)` to get a bitmap from camera.

videoControl is got from `player.getControl("VideoControl")` and `player` is got from `Manager.createPlayer()`

By the way, what kind of Image do you have? If we are talking of EncodedImage, you can just use `getBitmap()` from it.

Comment: Thanks, +1 but.... 
I have tried with EncodedImage but I wasn't able to get the correct filepath. Please se the code below and the code added to the question
        EncodedImage image = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource(filePath);
        byte[] array = image.getData();
        capturedBitmap = image.getBitmap();